# How do I get and pass the field of the row having class="name" in the following html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gibberish</td>
            <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
            <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
            <td>$999.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="fetchdata(parameter)">Fetch Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the above html, I want that the function fetchdata('*parameter*') to contain the text content of the td which has a class of name and is hidden, as the parameter.

OR

I need a way in which I can get the text content of the td having class of name in my javascript function.
i.e.

```
function fetchdata() {
  const name = document.somethingThatGivesMeName()
}
```

NOTE: There are going to be multiple rows that I may require to get the name of so I can't directly do `document.queryselector('.name')`

Sorry, This might be pretty simple but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: If there might be multiple rows with the name, how do you know which one of them to get?

Comment: I want to access it using parentElement property but how do I use it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking the button find the first row up in the tree relative to the button with the `closest` method. Then from the row select the element with the class `name` and read the `textContent` or `innerText` of that element.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-fetch-details');

function fetchDetails(event) {
  const row = event.target.closest('tr');
  const name = row.querySelector('.name').textContent;
  console.log(name);
}

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', fetchDetails));
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>gibberish</td>
      <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
      <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
      <td>$999.00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="js-fetch-details">Fetch Details</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the quotes `'`:

```js
function fetchdata(value){
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gibberish</td>
            <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
            <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
            <td>$999.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="fetchdata('parameter')">Fetch Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

or you can use event listener and data value:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log(e.dataset.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gibberish</td>
            <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
            <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
            <td>$999.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <button data-value="parameter">Fetch Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('name')`

This will get all the elements that have class of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

First you get all elements with class="name", then you pick just (the first) one with the attribute "hidden".

It's a way to do it anyway.

```js
function fetchdata() {
  const tds = document.getElementsByClassName("name")
  for(let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
    if(tds[i].getAttribute("hidden") != null) {
      console.log(tds[i].innerHTML)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">gibberish</td>
    <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
    <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
    <td>$999.00</td>
    <td class="name">1</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="fetchdata()">Fetch Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With **jQuery** you can just do:

```js
function fetchdata() {
  console.log($('.name[hidden]').html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>gibberish</td>
    <td class="name" hidden>200398</td>
    <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
    <td>$999.00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="fetchdata()">Fetch Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that you need to have a **table** around your structure for any of this to work properly. You can't have **tbody**, **tr** and **td** outside a **table**.

Comment: I misread the question originally, I think now this solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would put the listener on the `<tbody>` instead.

```
document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Clicking on the whole row
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'TR') {
    const name = e.target.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    console.log(name);
  }

  // Clicking on the button
  // Give the button a class
  if (e.target.classList.contains('.somebuttonclass')) {
    const name = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    console.log(name);
  }
});
```

UPDATE

closest would also work

```
document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Clicking on the whole row
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'TR') {
    const name = e.target.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    console.log(name);
  }

  // Clicking on the button
  // Give the button a class
  if (e.target.classList.contains('.somebuttonclass')) {
    const name = e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('.name').textContent;
    console.log(name);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use document.getElementsByClassName you will get what you want.
However, if there will be a case where more than one instance of that class name will occur, then you need to iterate through the classes and get their values.
The following should solve your problem

```
<html>
 <head>
<script>
 function fetchdata(){
var data = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
var t = data.length;
for(i = 0; i< t; i++){
var content = data[i].innerHTML;
alert (content);
}
}
</script>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gibberish</td>
            <td class="data" hidden>200398</td>
            <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
            <td>$999.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="fetchdata()">Fetch Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```